# Acumatica - Web services sample code in Java

Tags: java, web-services, acumatica

Has anyone written Acumatica Web Services in Java Language?  We need some sample code of any screen in Acumatica.

Thank you,
Sharif A

Answer (score 5):

Sharif,

Here's a command line sample I wrote a long time ago. The following assumptions are used in this example:

1. Client application access Acumatica ERP instance installed with demo
   application database. Web Services WSDL definition file is imported
   and proxy class generated in AR303000 package.
2. Web Services WSDL definition file is imported and proxy class
   generated in AR303000 package.

   ```
   private static String getCookie(BindingProvider port) {
           Map<String, ?> headers = (Map<String, ?>) port.getResponseContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);

           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

           List<String> cookie = (List<String>) headers.get("Set-Cookie");

           for (String c : cookie) {
                   int idx = c.indexOf(";");
                   if (idx != -1) {
                           sb.append(c.substring(0, idx));
                   } else
                           sb.append(c);
                   sb.append("; ");
           }

           return sb.toString();
   }

   private static void setCookie(BindingProvider port, String value) {
           port.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Collections.singletonMap("Cookie", Collections.singletonList(value)));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Screen service = new Screen();
       ScreenSoap screen = service.getScreenSoap();

       LoginResult lres = screen.login("admin", "123");

       String cookie = getCookie((BindingProvider) screen);
      setCookie((BindingProvider) screen, cookie);

       Content content = screen.getSchema();      

       ArrayOfCommand commands = new ArrayOfCommand();
       commands.getCommand().add(content.getCustomerSummary().getServiceCommands().getEveryCustomerID());
       commands.getCommand().add(content.getCustomerSummary().getCustomerName());
       commands.getCommand().add(content.getGeneralInfoMainAddress().getCity());

       ArrayOfArrayOfString result = screen.export(commands, null, 0, true, true);
       List<ArrayOfString> lines = result.getArrayOfString();

       for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
       {
           List<String> currentLine = lines.get(i).getString();
           System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", currentLine.get(0), currentLine.get(1));
       }       
     }   
   }
   ```

Comment: [here is my old article][1]


  [1]: http://forum.acumatica.com/forum/acumatica-reseller-and-isv-community/development-and-customization/740-api-how-to-create-api-project-and-use-it-with-c-php-java?p=3391#post3391